# Ubuntu Server 16.04.02 with Splash Screen and Kiosk mode

Tags: boot, server, plymouth, openbox, kiosk

I'm trying to configure a Ubuntu Server 16.04.02 in Kiosk mode with Chrome. It's working but I'm not able to configure a Splash Screen instead of showing boot messages.

**Working so far**

Steps to create my Chrome Kiosk

1. Installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.02 with OpenSSH Server
2. Updates: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`
3. Display Server + Windows Manager: `sudo apt install xorg openbox -y`

   Note: I tried to install openbox with `--no-install-recommends` but half of the screen (right side) was black.
4. Google Chrome

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main'
   wget -qO- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
   sudo apt update && sudo apt install google-chrome-stable -y
   ```
5. Create a "Kiosk" user: `sudo adduser kiosk`
6. Start Script for Chrome:

   ```
   sudo tee -a /home/kiosk/startchrome.sh <<EOF
   #!/bin/bash

   # Turn off DPMS (Display Power Management Signaling)
   xset -dpms

   # Disable screen saver blanking
   xset s off

   # Start OpenBox
   openbox-session &

   # Make sure Chrome is always started - restart if needed
   while true; do
     rm -rf ~/.{config,cache}/google-chrome/
     google-chrome --ignore-certificate-errors --kiosk --no-first-run --disable-infobars --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-translate         'http://localhost:8080'
   done
   EOF
   ```

   Make it executable and run on login:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /home/kiosk/startchrome.sh
   echo "/usr/bin/startx /etc/X11/Xsession /home/kiosk/startchrome.sh -- :0 &> /dev/null" | sudo tee -a /home/kiosk/.profile
   ```
7. Configure Auto-Login:

   Configure Getty:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/
   sudo tee -a /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf <<EOF
   [Service]
   ExecStart=
   ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --skip-login --noissue --autologin kiosk --noclear %I $TERM
   Type=idle
   EOF
   ```

   Enable Getty:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable getty@tty1.service
   ```
8. Hide Banner message on boot

   ```
   sudo touch /home/kiosk/.hushlogin
   sudo chown kiosk:kiosk /home/kiosk/.hushlogin
   ```

**Problem - X not starting**

I want to remove all Boot Messages. I tried `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` in `/etc/default/grub` but now, all I see is a little cursor at the top left of the screen. Chrome is not displayed anymore?

**Solution**

The kiosk user must be added to the video group! Don't know why it was working before I installed plymouth:

```
    sudo usermod -a -G audio kiosk
    sudo usermod -a -G video kiosk
```

Note: I tried my own procedure in Ubuntu 17.04 and i had to do those additional steps:

```
    sudo apt install xserver-xorg-legacy
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-legacy
```

Now you select "Anyone" on the menu. Than modify `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` and set:

```
    needs_root_rights=yes
    allowed_users=anybody
```

**Question - How to configure a new theme**

I also want a Splash Screen, I think that I have to install plymouth? What should I install and how to configure it?

**Solution**

I created a theme based on ubuntu-logo and copied it in `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/` than I did:

```
    sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/MY_THEME/MY_THEME.plymouth 150
    sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

It will ask for theme selection, I select mine and after you must do:

```
    sudo update-initramfs -u
    sudo update-grub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I'm just asking for help with the same settings but applied to **18.04**. Could you please take a look here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043532/ubuntu-server-18-04-hide-disable-all-boot-messages-kiosk-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boot messages are avoided by `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`. I don't know why you still get the cursor though.

Anyway, to answer your question about the plymouth, you want to install it by running the command `sudo apt-get install plymouth`. This should install it to the system. Then, your want to copy all of the contents of `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo` to another folder (Preferably somewhere in the `/usr/share/plymouth/themes` directory). Then, your most likely want to change the image `ubuntu-logo` in your newly copied folder. Then, to make the change to the new boot logo, edit the configuration file for plymouth located at `/etc/alternatives/default.plymouth`. There, change the address for the two lines below to the new folder you created earlier:

```
ImageDir=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo
ScriptFile=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script
```

So, for example, I might edit the lines to be like this:

```
ImageDir=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/mytheme
ScriptFile=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/mytheme/ubuntu-logo.script
```

Then, save the configuration and reboot. You now should have your boot logo image instead of the regular Ubuntu one.

Comment: Thanks for explanations on plymouth, but I have to fix grub first. As soon as I set "quiet splash" all I see is a black screen. Chrome no more visible :S

Comment: What is your graphics card? Sometimes it can have an affect on the bootup process.

Comment: Intel HD Graphics 500

Comment: Got it!! `sudo usermod -a -G audio kiosk && sudo usermod -a -G video kiosk`

Comment: Nice! What are you going to use the kiosk for?

Comment: It's a surveillance system, the kiosk is running our softwares with a web interface.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea!

Comment: My Theme is working now, but instead of manually changing the `/etc/alternatives/default.plymouth` file, I did and install. I edited my question with the solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the mouse cursor, when you make the startchrome.sh executable (Make it executable and run on login:) just add -nocursor e.g.:

```
sudo chmod +x /home/kiosk/startchrome.sh  
echo "/usr/bin/startx /etc/X11/Xsession /home/kiosk/startchrome.sh -- -nocursor :0" | sudo tee -a /home/kiosk/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

my entries for [grub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTYjz.jpg) ,you can check your possible resolution with `sudo hwinfo --framebuffer`

if entries are done `sudo update-grub`

if working n editing on plymouth / grub its never a mistake to run `sudo update-initramfs -u` behind