# Kiosk Setup - Cannot get X to start when "splash" enabled

Tags: grub2, xorg, plymouth, kiosk

I have a mostly working setup using Ubutnu Server 16.04. Until I enable the splash

I have the following set up

`$HOME/.xinitrc`

```
if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]
then
    for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*
    do
        [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
    done
    unset f
fi
exec openbox-session
```

The openbox session uses it's `autostart` script to start my application

`$HOME/.bash_profile`

```
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && [ -n "$XDG_VTNR" ] && [ "$XDG_VTNR" -eq 1 ]; then
  exec startx -- -nocursor
fi
```

`/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf`

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin kiosk --noclear %I $TERM
```

I have `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` in `/etc/default/grub`

The issue I am having is that when the boot is finished, I get put on `tty7` (I think...) and my x session never starts. If I use `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to go to `tty1`, then I see a bunch of failed attempts to start X, and after some seconds it tries again and everything starts up fine.

If I remove the `"splash"` from the grub config and do an `update-grub` then everything works as expected (minus the desired boot splash of course)

The `kiosk` user is in both the `audio` and `video` groups

I tried following [this setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924993/ubuntu-server-16-04-02-with-splash-screen-and-kiosk-mode) but that still did not work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem for some time, though fortunately I eventually found a solution.

Try doing this:

Open the 10_linux file in the Nano text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/10_linux
```

and then look for the line

```
set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
```

and change the number 7 to 1. That is if you want to use tty1 after bootup. You can of course change the number to whichever tty number you would like to 'handoff' the control to.

After you do that, save the file.

To finish up run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and violà! there you go - it should now boot up every time to tty1 (or to whichever tty number you've chosen); even after a 'quiet splash' bootup.

That's what worked for me, hope it solves it for you too.

Good luck!