# Kiosk Mode Surface

Tags: server, kiosk

I was following this [Guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924993/ubuntu-server-16-04-02-with-splash-screen-and-kiosk-mode/925002#925002?newreg=12674bb463c44ef385b9e45a7deda8ee) to make a kiosk for an ubuntu tablet but I seem to run into an issue I cant seem to bring up the on screen keyboard. This is not a public kiosk just a tablet that is use as a kiosk for home assistant

Comment: sorry I am using ubuntu server 22.04.1 LTS and this is on a surface

Comment: I'm not aware of an onscreen keyboard that will work on a text only server system.  All onscreen keyboards I've used require Xorg or a GUI (*with the onscreen keyboard being drawn in graphics on the display for the user to use, which doesn't exist on a server based system without Xorg*)

Comment: Yes i am aware that ubuntu server is a text based system but it does have xorg installed auto running with firefox on boot but is there a config that i can modify to bring osk up when a text field is selected?